# Converting NSString to a decimal

Tags: objective-c

I need to change the code below to make "intAmount" a decimal or an integer (i.e. a person can enter .10 or 1) in my uitextfield. The last line "myProduct" has to be a decimal not an integer and return the product in the format "18.00" for example. Can someone help someone help me alter my code snippit for this?

```
//amt has to be converted into a decimal value its a NSString now
NSInteger intAmount = [amt intValue];
//where total gets updated in the code with some whole (integer) value
NSInteger total=0;
//Change myProduct to a decimal with presicion of 2 (i.e. 12.65)
NSInteger myProduct=total*intAmount;
```

THIS DOESN'T WORK

```
NSDecimalNumber intAmount = [amt doubleValue];
//Keep in mind totalCost is an NSInteger
NSDecimalNumber total=totalCost*intAmount;
```

Comment: You don't mean 'decimal' you mean 'non-integer' or 'fraction'.  Decimal is a base.

Comment: decimal is also a class ... better than fl;oat or double - at least in C#. I would keep both `total` and `intInteger` as "decimal", but perform a cast right before an assignment. You then just need to find a way to convert a string to a "decimal". Just though I would simplify the workflow for you a bit. http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=900938

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: This question is clearly about Cocoa/Objective-C, so there is no such class as "decimal."

Comment: NSDecimalNumber is class, not a primitive type, you can't use it like this.

Comment: NSDecimalNumber is just a wrapper around the NSDecimal structure, isn't it?

Comment: @dreamlax: yes and no.  NSDecimalNumber is a subclass of NSNumber and it declares methods to do basic arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 3):

Use `doubleValue` instead of `intValue` to get the correct fractional number out of your text field.  Put it in a variable of type `double` rather than `NSInteger`.  Then use the format `%.2g` when you print it out and it will look like you want it to.

Comment: you must use double not NSDecimalNumber. Still though %.2g wont put zeros in (i.e. if the total is 3.60 it reads 3.6 and if the total is 36 it reads 36, it should read 36.00)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to track decimal values explicitly, you can use `NSDecimalNumber`. However, if all you're doing is this one operation, Carl's solution is most likely adequate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string representation of a real number (non-integer), you can use an [`NSScanner`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object to scan it into a `double` or `float`, or even an `NSDecimal` structure if that is your true intention (the NSDecimal struct and NSDecimalNumber class are useful for containing numbers that can be exactly represented in decimal).

```
NSString *amt = @"1.04";
NSScanner *aScanner = [NSScanner localizedScannerWithString:amt];
double theValue;

if ([aScanner scanDouble:&theValue])
{
    // theValue should equal 1.04 (or thereabouts)
}
else
{
    // the string could not be successfully interpreted
}
```

The benefit to using a localised `NSScanner` object is that the number is interpreted based on the user's locale, because “1.000” could mean either one-thousand or just one, depending on your locale.